# Google cloud task disappears

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

We built an app that heavily rely on google cloud task, but as our user base is increasing we are pushing 100s of cloud task in a queue. While 99%+ of task gets executed correctly, there are few that just disappear.

It's a very strange issue. Having no logs adds salt to injury. I added custom logs in my application to print task name.

My application A --> create cloud tasks --> calls another application B

A creates CT successfully but B receives 99%+ tasks only, not 100%.

Example this ask:
locations/asia-south1/queues/tpl-pending/tasks/88947425534926389671

Comment: Are you sure that the task are correctly created? Are the names unique?

Comment: In addition to guillaume questions could you please answer the following: what's the configuration for task deadline of the queue? Is a single queue handling all the requests? What's the push rate to the queue? what's the endpoint of these tasks GAE, Cloud Function,..?